# Merge sort in python issue

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

```
def mergeSort(A, l, r):
    if l < r:
        mid = (l + r) // 2
        mergeSort(A, l, mid)
        mergeSort(A, mid + 1, r)
        merge(A, l, mid, r)

def merge(arr, l, mid, r):
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []

    for i in range(mid):
        arr1.append(arr[i])

    for j in range(mid, r):
        arr2.append(arr[j])

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    while (i < len(arr1) and j < len(arr2)):
        if arr1[i] < arr2[j]:
            arr[k] = arr1[i]
            i += 1
        else:   
            arr[k] = arr2[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < len(arr1):
        arr[k] = arr1[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < len(arr2):
        arr[k] = arr2[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1


arr = [2, 9, 7, 6, 1, 8, 4, 3]
mergeSort(arr, 0, 8)

print(arr)
```

There's a slight mistake somewhere in the code that I'm not able to find
Please try to run this code on your machine with different test cases.
And Let me know what I'm doing wrong here.
I don't know why I'm getting an incorrect answer: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7]`

Comment: Have you attempted to debug your code?

Comment: Of course, I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems with indexes. You wrote code in C style.
Just use slices to fix your problem

Change definition (delete for loops for arr1 and arr2) for arr1 and arr2 to :

```
arr1 = arr[:mid]
arr2 = arr[mid:]
```

Comment: Sure, it gives me the correct output. But, what was wrong with my code

Comment: I'm afraid this works only by coincidence. The initialization should be `arr1 = arr[l : mid]` and `arr2 = arr[mid : r]` but there are other problems in `mergesort()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    else:   
        arr[k] = arr2[j]
        j += 1
    k += 1
```

Change the place of 
   k += 1
To this:

```
    else:   
        arr[k] = arr2[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1
```

Or this:

```
    else:   
        arr[k] = arr2[j]
        j += 1
k += 1
```

Comment: NO, it doesn't work. What you're implying is the same thing I already did

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you pass the index of the first element to sort and the index once past the last element of the slice, but you wrote the function `mergeSort` with different semantics as you assume `r` to be the index to the last element of the slice.
- similarly, `merge` expects the `mid` argument to be the start of the right half and you pass `mid`, which would be the index to the last element of the first half in your approach.
- in the `merge` function, `arr1` should be initialized with `i` varying from `l` to `mid`, with `for i in range(l:mid):`
- furthermore, `k` must be initialized to `l`, not `0`.
- note that `arr1` and `arr2` could be initialized from simple slices of `arr`.

Here is a modified version:

```py
def mergeSort(A, l, r):
    if r - l > 1:
        mid = (l + r) // 2
        mergeSort(A, l, mid)
        mergeSort(A, mid, r)
        merge(A, l, mid, r)

def merge(arr, l, mid, r):
    arr1 = arr[l : mid]
    arr2 = arr[mid : r]

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = l

    while (i < len(arr1) and j < len(arr2)):
        if arr1[i] <= arr2[j]:
            arr[k] = arr1[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = arr2[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < len(arr1):
        arr[k] = arr1[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < len(arr2):
        arr[k] = arr2[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

arr = [2, 9, 7, 6, 1, 8, 4, 3]
mergeSort(arr, 0, 8)

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```